# Trying to get the links when clicked to show the data in the divs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdo

I am not sure why this is not working. When I click the links the data suppose to show up in the divs, but for some reason nothing is showing up. Anyone have any suggestion on why that is? I am not sure if my script is setup right.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <title>test</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script>
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        var div_id = $(this).data('id');

        $('.toggle_content').hide();
        $('#' + div_id).toggle();
    });
    </script>
      </head>
      <body>

      <nav>

       <a href="#" target="_top" data-id="one">Received</a>
       <a href="#" target="_top" data-id="one">
      <?php 
       //conects to the database
        require_once("../db_connect.php");
      $stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows_cnt FROM receivingrequests WHERE status='Received'");
      $stmt->execute();
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))    {
        echo $row['rows_cnt'];
      }

      ?></a>


        <br>


        <a href="#" data-id="two">Info Div #2</a><br>&nbsp;<a href="#" data-id="three">Info Div #3</a> 
        <br> 
        <a href="#" data-id="four">Info Div #4</a> 
    </nav>

    <div id="one" class="toggle_content">
     <?php
        //conects to the database
        require_once("../db_connect.php");

        //prepared statement with PDO to query the database
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM receivingrequests WHERE Status='RECEIVED'");
        $stmt->execute();

        ?>

        <?php //start of the while loop ?>
        <?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>
     <table border="1" style="border: thin #000000; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; display: table;" class="style1">

        <tr> 
            <th style="width:15%; background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
            <strong>Request#</strong></th>
            <th style="width:15%; background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
            <strong>Status</strong></th>
            <th style="width:20%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
            <strong>Comments</strong></th>
            <th style="width:10%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
            <strong>Date Requested</strong></th>
            <th style="width:20%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
            <strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th style="width:10%;  background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
            <strong>Department</strong></th>
        <th style="width:10%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>VasLblDate</strong></th>


        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php $id = $row['RequestNumber'];?>
        <?php echo  "<td> <a href='../update.php?id=$id'>$id</a></td>"?>

            <td class="style2" style="width: 62px"><strong><?php echo $row['Status']; ?></strong></td>
            <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Comments']; ?></strong></td>
            <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['DATEREQUESTED']; ?></strong></td>
            <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['EmpName']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Department']; ?></strong></td>
            <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['VasLbDate']; ?></strong></td>

        </tr>
        </table>
     <?php } //end of the while loop?>
    </div>


    <div id="two" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... Two</div>
    <div id="three" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... Three</div>
    <div id="four" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... Four</div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

 <script src="../javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>



      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: The DOM may not be ready-  try putting your script at the bottom of the page and see if that helps.

Comment: I don't see the jquery in your scripts. Did you include it?

Comment: sorry I do have it in my page for some reason when I copied and pasted forgot to leave it in. It is not working with it in. I will try putting script at the bottom suggested by TJ

Comment: I had two errors I removed the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css looks that was one error it was outdated version. The last error I have is  Object doesn't support property or method 'on' looks like it is from my script. <script>
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var div_id = $(this).data('id');

    $('.toggle_content').hide();
    $('#' + div_id).toggle();
});
</script>

Comment: That's with the script at the bottom when I put the script back at the top I get this error SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined

Comment: that's because you're loading jquery at the BOTTOM of your script, and trying to use it at the TOP of the script. then you do `$('a')`, that part of the html hasn't been loaded/parsed yet, so you're attaching your handlers to nothing.

Comment: I added the script to the top and I get this error SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined

Comment: I think it has to do with the version of Jquery I am using I am going to check into that

Comment: nothing to do with jquery. `$ undefined` means jquery isn't loaded yet. you should have `<script src="jquery.js"></script><script>...your other code here...</script>`

Comment: I added this and it worked     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

   <script>
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var div_id = $(this).data('id');
    
    $('.toggle_content').hide();
    $('#' + div_id).toggle();
});
</script>

Comment: Only thing that is not working is the table does not want to stay shown the other links are showing up. The table opens then closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong Jquery. I also needed to put the Jquery script at the bottom of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>test</title>

    <link href="../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>
  <body background="../images/background.jpg">

  <nav>

   <a href="#" target="_top" data-id="one">Received</a>
   <a href="#" target="_top" data-id="one">
  <?php 
   //conects to the database
    require_once("../db_connect.php");
  $stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows_cnt FROM receivingrequests WHERE status='Received'");
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))    {
    echo $row['rows_cnt'];
  }

  ?></a>


    <br>


    <a href="#" data-id="two">Info Div #2</a><br>&nbsp;<a href="#" data-id="three">Info Div #3</a> 
    <br> 
    <a href="#" data-id="four">Info Div #4</a> 
</nav>

<div id="one" class="toggle_content">
 <?php
    //conects to the database
    require_once("../db_connect.php");

    //prepared statement with PDO to query the database
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM receivingrequests WHERE Status='RECEIVED'");
    $stmt->execute();

    ?>

    <?php //start of the while loop ?>
    <?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>
 <table border="1" style="border: thin #000000; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; display: table;" class="style1">

    <tr> 
        <th style="width:15%; background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Request#</strong></th>
        <th style="width:15%; background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Status</strong></th>
        <th style="width:20%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Comments</strong></th>
        <th style="width:10%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Date Requested</strong></th>
        <th style="width:20%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Name</strong></th>
        <th style="width:10%;  background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
        <strong>Department</strong></th>
    <th style="width:10%; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;" class="style3">
    <strong>VasLblDate</strong></th>


    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php $id = $row['RequestNumber'];?>
    <?php echo  "<td> <a href='../update.php?id=$id'>$id</a></td>"?>

        <td class="style2" style="width: 62px"><strong><?php echo $row['Status']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Comments']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['DATEREQUESTED']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['EmpName']; ?></strong></td>
    <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['Department']; ?></strong></td>
        <td class="style2"><strong><?php echo $row['VasLbDate']; ?></strong></td>

    </tr>
    </table>
 <?php } //end of the while loop?>
</div>


<div id="two" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... Two</div>
<div id="three" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... Three</div>
<div id="four" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... Four</div>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

   <script>
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var div_id = $(this).data('id');

    $('.toggle_content').hide();
    $('#' + div_id).toggle();
});
</script>


  </body>
</html>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, for running any code you want to run *after* the page has fully loaded, get into the habit of surrounding your code with this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

So for the your page, you'll want this:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('a').on('click', function() {
            var div_id = $(this).data('id');

            $('.toggle_content').hide();
            $('#' + div_id).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

As one of the other posters has mentioned, you need to add JQuery to your project.

First, create a folder called "jquery" inside your web-page's directory. Then download the latest JQuery js file and save it inside your the "jquery" directory.

The latest JQuery (accurate at the time of posting this comment) is here.
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js

After that, add this code to where the other links are:

```
<link href="jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then adjust your href as necessary depending on whether your web-page is in the root directory or one of the sub-directories for your site.

Comment: I just posted that on my comment before you posted the answer

Comment: I know you did. Have you referenced the correct folder? Sometimes you can think you're pointing to the right folder and instead need to change the directory.